# When did each Horcrux get destroyed in the Harry Potter movies?

Tags: harry-potter

I have just watched the last of the Harry Potter movies for the second time on a long flight and my brain was addled through lack of sleep. As far as I remember, three of the eight horcruxes were destroyed in that movie.

But I couldn't make my memory add the total destroyed up to eight across the movies. So when were they all destroyed, in which movie and by whom? And does the total add up to 8?

Comment: I thought the first horrocrux was Professor Quirrel. He was destroyed in Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, by Harry Potter, with his hands. Remember Harry was the horrocrux never ment to be so, technically, there were eight horrocruxes.

Comment: No, Quirrel was possessed by Voldemort, but not a horcrux.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Horcrux hunt was a mission given to Harry Potter in **June of 1997** to find all of **Lord Voldemort's** remaining **Horcruxes** and destroy them. The mission fell to **Harry Potter** to complete. He was joined by **Hermione Granger** and **Ron Weasley**, and they set off in the aftermath of **Bill Weasley** and **Fleur Delacour's** wedding.

**Lord Voldemort's** had only seven Horcruxes:

1. Tom Riddle's diary. **->** Destroyed by Harry Potter in [Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0295297/)
2. Marvolo Gaunt's Ring.  **->** Destroyed by Albus Dumbledore in [Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0417741/)
3. Salazar Slytherin's Locket.  **->** Destroyed by Ronald Weasley in [Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part I](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0926084/)  with Gryffindor's sword.
4. Helga Hufflepuff's Cup. **->** Destroyed by Hermione Granger in [Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201607/)
5. Rowena Ravenclaw's Diadem.  **->** Destroyed by Harry Potter in [Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201607/)
6. Harry Potter (unknown to Voldemort until after he had "destroyed" him)  **->** Destroyed in [Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201607/)
7. Nagini the Snake.  **->** Destroyed by Neville Longbottom in [Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201607/)

**Voldemort** also retained part of his soul inside him.

They eventually destroyed all of the Horcruxes by **2 May 1998**. The hunt ended with the death of **Lord Voldemort** at the hands of **Harry Potter** at the end of the **Battle of Hogwarts** and this is in [**Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201607/)

I hope [harrypotter.wikia.com](http://www.harrypotter.wikia.com) has plenty of well constructed resources.

According to Albus Dumbledore, Lord Voldemort created seven horcruxes. Throughout the books and movies, five out of the seven that he created had been destroyed.

Harry Potter was an accidental horcrux. According to Dumbledore seven horcrux were created before the killing of Harry Potter's parents, so Harry would have been the 8th horcrux. The snake was a horcrux at a later time seeing how the snake never existed during the time that the first horcruxes were created.

Dumbledore said that there was one horcrux in each house of Hogwarts. The horcrux related to the house of Gryffindor was never found.

Comment: Slytherin's locket was not destroyed until Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows.

Comment: Regulus only retrieved the locket.  He did not remove the curse on it.  To destroy the piece of Voldemort's soul that it contained the locket had to be destroyed or damaged so badly it couldn't be repaired.  Ron, after being mentally tortured by the locket with images of Harry and Hermione together, destroyed it in the Forest of Dean with Godric Gryffindor's sword in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows.

Comment: But,that's the way i interpret it.

Comment: Mmm. In the Deathly Hallows they steal the real locket back from Dolores Umbridge and then spend a lot of the time carrying it around, passing it from person to person because of the negative emotions it imposes on them.  They spend the time trying to work out how to destroy it and eventually do so like @Legion600 describes.  I'm not sure interpretation is really necessary - it seems pretty clearly spelled out.  If you disagree still, re-edit your answer back and I'll upvote Legion's answer instead.  Your answer is potentially the best apart from this (IMHO) error.

Comment: @iandotkelly,i agree with ur views and Legion600's:)Of course. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Technically, the ring was destroyed in the events between the fifth and sixth movies.  I can't recall the sixth movie well enough to know if we saw that in a flashback or just learned about it.

Comment: Also technically it is **Crabbe** who destroys Rowena Ravenclaw's Diadem and dies along the way by casting *Fiendfyre*

Comment: Harry Potter was destroyed in Harry Potter 

Comment: **Harry was _not_ a Horcrux!!**

Comment: @NikitaNeganov Thats only in the books. This question is specifically asking about the movies where Harry stabs it with a basilisk fang after the Fiendfyre incident.

Comment: If Voldemort created 7 Horcruxes not including Harry, then your list is missing one.

Answer (score 18):

Riddle's Diary destroyed by Harry in Chamber of Secrets with Basilisk fang

Marvolo Gaunt's ring destroyed by Dumbledore in Half Blood Prince with Gryffindor's sword but not shown.

Slytherin's locket destroyed by Ron in Deathly Hallows Part I with Gryffindor's sword.

Helga Hufflepuff's Cup destroyed by Hermione with a Basilisk fang in Deathly Hallows Part II

Diadem of Ravenclaw destroyed by Harry with Basilisk fang and then thrown into Fiendfyre in Deathly Hallows Part II

Harry Potter killed by Voldemort in Deathly Hallows Part II

Nagini killed by Neville "Badass" Longbottom in Deathly Hallows Part II with the sword of Gryffindor

The eighth piece of Voldemort's soul was inside of him and it died with him.

Answer (score 5):

Tom Riddle's Diary: Harry Potter with a Basilisk Fang. Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets.

Marvolo Gaunt's Ring: Dumbledore with Godric Gryffindor's Sword. Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince.

Salazar Slytherin's Locket: Ron Weasley with Godric Griffindor's Sword. Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1.

Hegla Hufflepuff's Cup: Hermione Granger with a Basilisk Fang. Harry Potter an the Deathly Hallows Part 2.

Rowena Ravenclaw's Diadem: Ron Weasley Kicking it into Gregory Goyle's fiendfyre spell. Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2.

Harry Potter: Lord Voldemort with a Killing Curse. Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2.

Nagini: Neville Longbottom with Godric Gryffindor's Sword. Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2.

That was all of Voldemort's Horcruxes but there is still the eighth part of his soul that lives inside him.

Lord Voldemort: Himself with His Backfiring Killing Curse, Harry Potter with the Elder Wand's Mastery. Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2.

Lord Voldemort's killing curse backfired because the wand was being used against its true master (Harry Potter), after Harry disarmed Draco Malfoy in the book Half-Blood Prince. (Draco had previously won the wand's allegiance from Albus Dumbledore when he disarmed him in the astronomy tower prior to his death at the hands of Severus Snape).

Comment: Also, priori incantatem only exists between wands that share the same core, not between people.

Comment: In response to JohnP: There was no priori incentatem between Harry's wand and Voldemort's wand as Voldemort was using the Elder Wand and Harry was using Draco's wand.

Comment: @DominicRead *"In response to someone"* can easily be done by `@someone`, which automatically notifies them of the response (otherwise it might just get lost).

Answer (score 4):

The Horcruxes were destroyed as follows.

1. Tom Riddle's Diary: by **Harry** inside the Chamber of Secrets using the basilisk fang in *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*.
2. Marvolo Gaunt's ring: by **Dumbledore** using Gryffindor's sword in *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*.
3. Salazar Slytherin's locket: by **Ron** using Gryffindor's sword in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows part 1*.
4. Helga Hufflepuff's cup: by **Hermione** using the basilisk fang in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows part 2*.
5. Rowena Ravenclaw's diadem: by **Crabbe** accidentally by a *[fiendfyre](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Fiendfyre)* in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows part 2*.
6. Harry Potter (specifically the soul fragment within him): by **Voldemort** using a Avada Kedavra in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows part 2*.
7. Nagini the snake: by **Neville** using Gryffindor's sword in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows part 2*.

Comment: To be technical, it was Fiendfyre, as normal fire would not have been able to destroy the diadem.