# Why does Harry say that there is only one Horcrux left, after only having destroyed 4?

Tags: harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-2

I'm aware what the horcruxes are in *Harry Potter* and am aware of the lore with part of Voldemort's soul being in Harry.

What I was wondering was that in Hogsmeade, talking to Aberforth in *Deathly Hallows: Part 2*, Harry states that...

> We've been hunting Horcruxes. 
>   We think the last one's inside the castle.

At this point he knows of having destroyed 4 and is not aware that he is one. This still leaves 2 horcruxes to destroy that Harry knows of (he finds out that these are the diadem and the snake later). Why does he state that "the last ONE" is in the castle when there should be TWO more left?

Comment: @JAD I don't think that's what the question is asking. The question doesn't ask why he thinks it's at Hogwarts but why he says there only *one* left when there should actually be *two* left.

Comment: If they didn't know Harry was one, wouldn't there be **three** horcruxes left, instead of two?

Comment: @JAD It seems without Harry, it's indeed [just 6 horcurxes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1354/49), the 7th is supposed to be Voldemort's very own soul.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Voldemort isn't a horcrux by the definition given in the books.  The 7th is Harry - an accidental creation.

Comment: @Tim Still, they were talking about 7 *before* they knew about Harry (whose status as a horcrux is debated, too). I don't know what the books say, but it doesn't seem all too relevant if it deviates from the films either.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson 6 horcruxes + Tom = 1 soul split into 7 parts.  That's the 7 mentioned.  With the attempt on Harry's life, Tom split again - making 8 parts in total.  But this was unintentional.

Comment: @Tim Yes, exactly. That's pretty much what I said in my comment, too. 6 horcruxes, 7 when counting Voldemort himself, 8 when counting Harry.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Voldemort is _not_ a horcrux.  His soul got split 8 ways - but there are only 7 horcruxes.

Comment: @Tim Sure, horcrux, souls, same difference. The point is, though, that I was referring to this: *"If they didn't know Harry was one, wouldn't there be three horcruxes left, instead of two?"* when saying there's only 6 not 7 (without Harry), which we both seem to agree about, unnecessary technicalities notwithstanding.

Comment: I've commented below on @Tim's answer. I understand the Harry bit. What I don't understand is that Harry knew the potential for 7 (including the bit left in Tom Riddle) based on Slughorn's memory. Surely he should either think there are two remaining  or he should be entirely unsure how many are left.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Because they didn't know the other Horcruxes existed.**

Only Dumbledore knew how many Voldemort had created.

The seven Horcruxes are:

- Tom Riddles diary
- Marvolo Gaunt's ring
- Salazar Slytherin's Locket
- Helga Hufflepuff's Cup
- Rowena Ravenclaw's Diadem
- Nagini the Snake
- Harry Potter

By the time Harry & co are talking to Alberforth, only the first 4 had been destroyed.

Harry *did not know* that he was one, and no one knew that Nagini was one.

Dumbledore only revealed the truth about Harry and Nagini after Harry's "death", when they talked in the spirit realm.

So at the time of the conversation, they only knew of one more Horcrux, the fifth one, the diadem.

That's why Harry said there's only one left.  He didn't know there were more.  Even Voldemort didn't know Harry was a Horcrux.

Comment: _"Even Voldemort didn't know Harry was a Horcrux."_ Isn't he the one that created/made them in the first place?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir When Voldemort attempted to murder Harry as a child, the spell rebounded and destroyed Volemort's physical form.  The same action _accidentally_ put a piece of Voldemort's soul into Harry, making Harry a Horcrux. It was pure accident, not intentional.  Dumbledore was the only one who figured it out.

Comment: The memory from Slughorn that Harry and Dumbledore watch in *Half Blood Prince* explicitly speaks about 7, though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson In Slughorn's memory, Tom says the number seven, meaning to split his soul into seven parts.  Those seven are the first six horcruxes, plus Tom himself. But Harry becoming one of them is pure accident.  In reality Voldemort ended up splitting his soul into _eight_ pieces.

Comment: @Tim Well, yes, exactly. You seemed to deny that when claiming Voldemort was never part of the count and it was only ever 6 before Harry came around, though. You also seem to ignore that when saying that Harry didn't know there was at least 2 more rather than 1. He watched Slughorn's memory, too.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Voldemort is _not_ a horcrux.  He only has 1/8th of a soul, but he's not a horcrux.  The horcrux is the object that's hiding a soul, not the person who made it.

Comment: Anyway, technicalities about what is a soul and what is a horcrux notwithstanding, there still remains the point that Harry should have known there's 6 rather than just 5 from Slughorn's memory.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson That assumes they think 6 were created.  At the time of the Alberforth conversation, Harry didn't know for certain.

Comment: I understand the Harry's soul bit. The source my confusion was the same as @NapoleonWilson's - from Slughorn's memory, Tom Riddle had specifically asked about creating 7 (including the bit that was left in himself). Why should Harry know there was 1 more (the diadem) but *not* know that there were 2 (the diadem and the snake)?

Comment: I might be missing something, but it is possible that Harry had no idea about Nagini and the snake getting killed (by a horcrux destroying artifact, even, not sure how it would apply to living things, though) before the final confrontation is just luck. Although being his last horcrux it would've probably done something noticeable and people would kill it anyway. Somewhere else in the books someone specifically points out that using a creature is a bad idea because killing a living horcrux kills both the creature and the soul fragment within.

Comment: Wrong. It is specifically mentioned in the books that Harry has a conversation with Neville before he goes into the forest, to quote "kill the snake". So Harry *does*, in fact, know that Nagini is a Horcrux before he goes into the forest to sacrifice himself. This comment is directed at @HTMLcoderexe

Comment: @Jayk I see. So I was indeed missing something...

Comment: @Tim, to continue on from what Napoleon Wilson was saying, No, Harry may not have known for certain (setting himself aside), but could of EASILY presumed from Slughorn's memory the others may exist.